# Error 53 on SQL Replication

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-replication

I am receiving this error while trying to setup replication between two SQL servers.

> Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent
>   SQLBASE-ECOMLIVE-ECOMLIVEpublication-VMVICTORIAN-16 failed. The
>   process could not read file
>   '\SQLBASE\EcometryReplication\unc\SQLBASE_ECOMLIVE_ECOMLIVEPUBLICATION\20160421151632\ITEMMAST_2.pre'
>   due to OS error 53.

I have a local SQL server, SQLBASE, that is the Distributor and Publisher. Another SQL server, VMVictorian, is the subscriber.

SQLBASE is on my local network. VMVictorian is on an AZURE VM. I have allowed traffic from the VM into the local network via our SonicWall. I can successfully connect to each other using SSMS. So, I believe the connections are ok.

The OS Error 53 sounds like a permissions issue... I was getting an Error 5 which I originally set it up and used a mapped drive (ie G:\blah) as the location for the location of the snapshot files. Once I changed that to a UNC path, that error went away.

I have shared the UNC path, obviously. I have allowed access to "Everybody".

Any thoughts on why there are issues?

Comment: FYI 53 is network path not found

Comment: Thank you for the reply. To understand what is expected, should the subscriber be able to reach that path? The publisher can access it. I have tried to see if the subscriber can, and it cannot.